# Unauthorized Access Error (C# console app) when attempting to write to a folder

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am having an issue with the Unauthorized Access Exception in my console app. I am getting a directory and deleting the contents and then writing new contents to it. I am able to delete the contents with no problem (no error), but when I attempt to write to the folder I get the unauthorized access exception. I have tried many possible solutions from threads all over the net, but nothing has worked. Currently the app is running with my credentials and should have full rights to the folder. Why would I be able to delete from the folder, but not write to it?

I'm running Windows 7.

What I'm attempting to do is take a pdf stream (from a url that auto-generates it) and save it to a folder.

My delete code looks like this:

```
Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath), delegate(string f) { File.Delete(f); });
```

And my write code looks like this:

```
writeStream = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\TestProjects", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

(At this line I get the error, but it doesn't go to the catch; it just keeps looping through this each time giving me the unauthorized error message.)

Comment: You usually get ahead by assuming the machine is right and you are wrong.  Like trying to delete files that don't exist, that always works.  And creating files that have the same name as a directory, TestProjects sure sounds like a directory name, not a file name.  That slaps you across the face with an access denied exception.

Comment: Hans - thank you very much for catching that writeStream issue. I completely missed that. I guess I was too close to the code myself. As for the delete code, I tested it with some random files that I put in the folder so I knew that was working.